# how to use localtime() correctly?

Tags: c++

In one of my utility programs, localtime() is used to covert unix timestamps to human readable date time.

The following code used to work in VS2010 while it fails to work in VS2019:

```
std::string sec = "1234123456";
int nsec = atoi(sec.c_str());
tm* t = localtime((time_t*)&nsec); // return null pointer
```

If I change the code in the following way, it will work also in VS2019:

```
std::string sec = "1234123456";
int nsec = atoi(sec.c_str());
time_t tt = nsec;
tm* t = localtime(&tt); // works
```

I have no idea why the additional int to time_t conversion is needed, any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably `time_t` is a 64bit type now so using `int` won’t work. The original code was dangerous anyway using direct casts without caring of the actual types.

Comment: Probably because `time_t` is actually bigger than an `int`, so the first cast is invoking undefined behavior.  That is, if `time_t` is a 64-bit type, then you're (improperly) telling C in the first example that a 4-byte `int` is one of those.

Comment: Note that your code will fail after 2038 due to using 32-bit timestamps

Comment: Did you read the [documentation of `localtime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime) ? Later, you could use it correctly.  Read also [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and enable all warnings in your compiler

Comment: On Linux systems read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) then [strptime(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html) and  [getdate(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdate.3.html) and [mktime(3)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mktime.3.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On most (if not all) modern compilers `time_t` is now a 64-bit integer. `(time_t*)&nsec` is therefore undefined behaviour as you are casting from one pointer type to a different one.

You fixed version is well defined but you will run into the reason that `time_t` is now 64-bit as 32-bit numbers will only work for times up to 2038 (assuming `time_t` is using the Unix epoch).

Unfortunately c++ doesn't provide a simple method for converting a `string` to `time_t`, to do it properly you'd need something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <charconv>

time_t str_to_time_t(const std::string& str)
{
    auto begin = str.c_str();
    auto end = begin + str.size();
    time_t time;
    auto result = std::from_chars(begin, end, time);
    if (result.ec != std::errc())
    {
        throw std::system_error(std::make_error_code(result.ec));
    }
    if (result.ptr != end)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("invalid time_t string");
    }
    return time;
}

int main()
{
    std::string sec = "1234123456";
    auto nsec = str_to_time_t(sec);
    tm* t = localtime((time_t*)&nsec);
    if (t)
    {
        std::cout << "parsed OK\n";
    }
}
```